# Como abrir um arquivo ao ser clicado em uma aplicação java?

Tags: java

Fiz uma aplicação em Java e quero abrir um determinado tipo de arquivo nele, como ocorre com o NetBeans, ou seja quando uma pessoa clica no arquivo ".java " ele abre no NetBeans( ou em outra IDE que aceite esse tipo de arquivo).
Contudo, mesmo que eu configure o arquivo para abrir na minha aplicação, ao ser aberto, não aparece o conteúdo dele na minha aplicação.
Há algum comando em java para fazer isso ?
A+

EDITED :

É bem por ai, mas não estou conseguindo bem fazer isso. Sei como abrir um arquivo ( já tenho um método para isso), mas não consigo chama-lo dentro passando o path pois dá erro.

segue o código:

```
// essa é uma das minhas classes ,é ela que é chamada e possui todos os componentes visuais
public static void main(  String args[]) {

public void run() {
                new Programa().setVisible(true);
                  if(args.length > 0) {
                        try {
                      MetodoAbir(args[0])





            }catch(Exception erro) {

            }

        }
```

Mas da  erro diz que o método não pode ser "refenrenciado por static contex". Isso ocorre até se eu colocar um método sem parâmetro, ou seja não consigo chamar os métodos ali. Também tentei criar uma variável global e jogar o valor args[0] nela para passar para o método em outro local  mas também da o mesmo erro.

Comment: Você quer configurar seu programa como padrão no windows, ou quer executar alguma aplicação dentro dele? Não está claro isso na pergunta.

Comment: Eu configurei ele como padrão. Quero executar algo dentro dele, mas quando clico no arquivo a aplicação abre mas não mostra o conteúdo do arquivo.

Comment: Você provavelmente esta recebendo o caminho do arquivo como parâmetro, mas não esta fazendo nada com ele.

Comment: Adicione o código responsável por esta execução, clicando em EDITAR na pergunta.

Comment: Como assim, no código   eu tenho que fazer uma verificação para saber se alguém clicou externamente em um arquivo quando abrir  a aplicação ? Se sim, como faço isso ?

Comment: @diegofm , é isso que eu estou querendo saber como verificar se algum arquivo foi clicado externamente para abri-lo na aplicação. Só sei fazer  isso usando o jfilechooser .

Comment: O que você já fez até agora? Adicione isso na pergunta, sua duvida já sabemos, agora você precisa mostrar onde quer colocar isso e como está o código atual onde você quer adicionar este recurso.

Answer (score 0):

Ao abrir a aplicação você tem de checar se não foi passado parâmetros para seu 
programa.

```
import java.io.File;

public class SeuPrograma {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length > 0) {
            File file = new File(args[0]);

            // Abra seu arquivo
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O principal você não disse, que é como abrir o arquivo.

Comment: Penso que o principal é estar ciente de que tem um arquivo chegando via linha de comando. Como abrir depende da logica do programa dele que eu não sei qual é. Pode ser um arquivo de texto, um zip, uma imagem, etc.

Comment: Mas a duvida justamente é *"Como abrir um arquivo ao ser clicado em uma aplicação java"* e a resposta não explicou nada disso. Eis o problema em se responder perguntas cuja a duvida não ficou clara o suficiente.

Comment: Edição feia na pergunta.

Comment: Agora fiz do jeito certo. Quando chama a classe principal passo como parâmetro o args para um construtor que recebe esse parâmetro da outra classe e depois faço o processo para abrir. Tá tudo certo, mas mesmo assim não aparece nada quando clico para abrir um arquivo . É como  se não tivesse passando nada quando clico em um arquivo.

Comment: Exiba uma mensagem com os parâmetros que seu programa esta recebendo e veja o que ocorre.